# Site collection Size

Tags: information-architecture

1. What is the maximum size we can have for a site collection. Microsoft says we can as much as a content DB and it is recommended to keep the size as 100GB for some maintainance reasons. Please suggesst whether can override this.
2. I need to store close 2 TB of data in SharePoint. I am thinking about having this information as flat in one site collection. I will capture the detailed meta data against each document and assign the corresponding taxonomy against each document. I am planning to create custom views to load the documents when the user loads the sharepoint. The custom view will load the filtered taxonomy according th user credentials and the list of documents will be displayed.

Please share your suggesstions.

Answer (score 1):

A quota specifies the storage limit values for the maximum amount of data that can be stored in a site collection. Quotas also specify the storage size that, when reached, triggers an e-mail alert to the site collection administrator. Quotas can be saved as quota templates, which can then be applied to any site collection in a SharePoint farm. Using quota templates rather than individual quotas can simplify setting storage limits on new site collections.

You can change the storage limit for the site collection manually. This overrides the limits set in the quota template that is currently applied to the site collection.

Have a look at the below links for more details,

[Manage site collection storage limits (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263480%28v=office.14%29.aspx#BKMK_Updatequotavaluesforsite)

[SharePoint Server 2010 capacity management: Software boundaries and limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Content DB Size Limit SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56598/content-db-size-limit-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 0):

Goog luck trying to backup (and pressumably restore) 2TB for data in one database :-)

"We strongly recommended limiting the size of content databases to 200 GB, except when the circumstances in the following rows in this table apply."
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx#SiteCollection