# Use SharePoint to share a windows directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

I have a situation where one of our departments have 100Gb they would like to share with an outside company. They both require to be able to modify the contents.
At the moment the data sits on out internal network on our SAN. I do not want to copy all 100GB to my SharePoint 2010 environment as I do not want to

1. replicate the data
2. have another 100GB in the content database.

Is there a way in SP2010 Enterprise that I can surface the shared directory in SharePoint so this external company can access the same information but through SharePoint?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can not. Why don't you just manage the data over sharepoint and delete it in the old place? Then you don't have the replicated data.
If you create a new SiteCollection you will get a new content database.

Reference for content-db size restrictions: [Content DB Size Limit SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56598/content-db-size-limit-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 1):

no I don't think there is anyway to do it with the out of the box interface - you can manage a SharePoint library through windows explorer but not a network drive through SharePoint's interface.

You can try to use the page view web part and link it to shared drive.

[Displaying a file or a folder in the Page Viewer Web Part](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2007/11/29/displaying-a-file-or-a-folder-in-the-page-viewer.aspx)

Another thing, You CAN index and search a networked drive on SharePoint.  Just create a new content source in the search settings on your shared services provider. I dont know whether it will work for external user or not?

Lastly: Why not simply upload the data to SharePoint site and remove from Shared drive. In SharePoint you will more control on the data and easy to share and collaborate.

Comment: Appears to to be working with the page view web part. I'll do some more testing externally and then mark as answer if it works. Many thanks

Comment: As the path is a UNC path it does not work externally