# Why 200GB content DB limit when using RBS

Tags: 2013, rbs

What's the point of using RBS when you are still restricted to 200GB content DB limit? I don't understand this thing.
Secondly this looks like recommended limit, right? Because SharePoint won't stop working all of a sudden if you go over this limit?

Answer (score 3):

200 GB is the suggested maximum limit to simplify your life and provides databases in manageable chunks. i dont think any body likes having to restore a 4TB database or BLOB data since it takes a while.Backup & Recovery make the things hard for administrators. If you deciede to go beyond the 200GB limit then follow things you have to check.

- Disk sub-system performance of 0.25 IOPS per GB. 2 IOPS per GB is
  recommended for optimal performance.
- You must have developed plans for high availability, disaster
  recovery, future capacity, and performance testing.
- Plus you have to make sure if you are spending more or less on hardware coste etc.

[SharePoint 2010 RBS and the 200GB content database limit](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29858/sharepoint-2010-rbs-and-the-200gb-content-database-limit)

Comment: As someone who currently has to work with a 3TB content database, I can confirm that it is NOT fun.

Answer (score 2):

200GB is the recommended size, but it can go upwards of 4TB. I imagine they still recommend not to go over 200GB in an RBS scenario incase you have to internalize the blobs. You wouldn't want to have a 3TB blob store and have to internalize it back into SQL server. Suddenly you have a mess on your hands.

When the DBs get that large, back up and recovery becomes more time consuming.